# What is T in YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS?

Tags: android, time

Android [Time#toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#toString%28%29) return YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS, What does "T" represent here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It represents the letter `T`, standing for the separator between the date and the... Time.

Used to produce an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant date/time string.

Comment: Used by google calendars